# django-celery : TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "NoneType") to tuple

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I have recently started using rabbitmq and celery with django. i am using django-celery, django-celery-email and post office to send emails in async way. 
After installing all these packages my settings.py looks like

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
#other apps
'djcelery',
'djcelery_email',
'post_office'
]


# setup celery
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()

# using post office as the default email backend 
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'post_office.EmailBackend'
# using djcelery's email backend as a backend for post office 

POST_OFFICE_BACKEND = 'djcelery_email.backends.CeleryEmailBackend'

POST_OFFICE = {
    'DEFAULT_PRIORITY' : 'now'
}

EMAIL_HOST = 'YOUR_HOST_NAME'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "YOUR_HOST_USER_NAME"
EMAIL_PORT = 25  # default smtp port
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "YOUR_HOST_USER_PASSWORD"
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'testing@example.com'
```

when i am trying to run django-celery via command

```
**python manage.py celeryd**
```

It is throughing below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/edyodavirtual/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/ubuntu/edyodavirtual/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/edyodavirtual/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 206, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/home/ubuntu/edyodavirtual/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 40, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/edyodavirtual/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/management/commands/celeryd.py", line 16, in <module>
    class Command(CeleryCommand):
  File "/home/ubuntu/edyodavirtual/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/management/commands/celeryd.py", line 20, in Command
    worker.get_options() +
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "NoneType") to tuple
```

Anyone here help me to fix this

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you start celery with `python manage.py celery worker`? Or did you already fix this?

Comment: same happens, i have this problem to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even i was facing the same issue, where i was trying to integrate celery with django via djcelery package. Then i read many blogs and documentation and found below conclusion.

**"Previous versions of Celery required a separate library to work with Django, but since 3.1 this is no longer the case. Django is supported out of the box now"**

[Celery Notes][1]http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

without using djcelery i wrote the tasks directly and it worked !

Answer (score 2):

Just comment out these lines in "~/anaconda2/envs/test_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djcelery/management/commands/celery.py " like this:

```
 14     #    options = (CeleryCommand.options +
 15     #           base.get_options() +
 16     #           base.preload_options)
```

then it works.

Comment: This worked for me, but an ideal fix... Any idea why this happened?